# wordpress sidebar widgets separated

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I got a Theme, which shows each post in a separated area.
Unfortunately the Sidebar is one big area which shows all widgets.

I wanted the widgets in the sidebar shows separated like the posts.

here is the code from sidebar.php:

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div><!-- end secondary -->
```

Is it possible to separate the widgets in the sidebar on an easy way?

I didn't found something about it on google :(

Comment: i translated it, my english is not the best but i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: you have to edit at least CSS but maybe PHP and HTML too, can't help more without see that theme

Comment: you can see the Theme online on svb-online.de - if you click on "aktuell" you see exactly what i mean with the posts and the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, add this CSS to your theme:

```
#secondary.widget-area {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

#secondary.widget-area .widget {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3d9;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}
```